# Facebook chat through instant messaging client?

Tags: facebook, chat

Does Facebook chat allow access through an IM client like Google Talk does?

Specifically, is there a way I can access it from Pidgin/Finch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Facebook Chat Support information](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php)...

In Pidgin:

- Go to "Accounts" and select "Manage accounts".
- On the Basic tab, enter the following info:

  - Protocol: XMPP
  - Username: [Your Facebook short URL/number]
  - Domain: chat.facebook.com
  - Resource: Pidgin
  - Password: [your Facebook password]
  - Local alias: [Your name]
- Click the Advanced tab, then enter the following info:

  - Connect port: 5222
  - Connect server: chat.facebook.com
  - (Untick the box labelled "Require SSL/TLS")

Answer (score 1):

[Detailed instructions](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) on how to set up facebook chat with most clients that support it can be found in their site tour section.

Answer (score 0):

[Digsby](http://www.digsby.com) also has Facebook chat support.